# Can't change purchased itunes videos to have media type other than Home Video

Tags: itunes

I have a number of files on my new Mac mini, imported into iTunes (12) from an external drive that had been serving as storage for my previous iTunes library on an old laptop that is now defunct.  For some reason, most of these video files got changed to have their media type be “home video”.  I have changed the media kind metadata on the files that were DVD rips, but I cannot change the media kind for the files that are iTunes purchases.  These identify (in the File tab) as “Protected MPEG-4 video file” and play fine.

I can also see these files through Home Sharing on iPads and my Apple TV.

Nonetheless, I can’t change the media kind to “Film” or “TV programme” as appropriate, which is very annoying. Is there any trick I might use to fix this?

Comment: That's strange. Works just fine for me. When you say you "can't change the media kind", what do you mean exactly? Do you have the dropdown menu under Get Info->Options->Media Kind? Do you get an error when attempting to change that?

Comment: Did you check permissions on those files?

Comment: I can change the titles on the files, so I can certainly edit some fields in the metadata.  When I do a `ls -l` on the files in their locations, I do also have write permission on them.

Comment: I open up the Get Info->Options->Media Kind dropdown menu and it only has one option (namely, “Home Video”) for these files.  The others (the DVD rips) present the full menu of possibilities.

Comment: I have the same problem. Permissions is not the issue. I have full access to the files. I also opened up some of the files with Subler to take a look at the metadata. The metadata showed the media kind was `TV Show`. But when I open the same files in iTunes the media kind is `Home Movies`.

Comment: I don't know why/how it happened, but a little while after I posted the original question, the purchased files “magically” had their media kinds update to the correct values without me having to do anything.  I speculate that some form of synchronisation/communication happened between the local install and the iTunes store, and that the correct remote information was allowed to supersede the local “this is a Home Video” data.

Comment: This post helped in my case: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/201076 
Best, 
Jan