# Can't change media kind from music to podcast in iTunes 12

Tags: iphone, itunes, podcasts

I've been downloading mp3s from a podcast's archives on their website (the archived episodes aren't available on iTunes). After adding these files to iTunes, I'm unable to do the logical thing, which is to change the media kind to Podcasts so it will show up under Podcasts and not Music. When I click Get Info > Options, Music is the only option in the dropdown.

[image]

It seems this solution used to work in previous versions of iTunes. Has anyone figured out a workaround? I really don't want to have to switch to the Music app to listen to these mp3s.

Note: Some people elsewhere seemed to think turning off iTunes Match would help, but I don't even have Match, so that's not a solution for me.

Answer (score 3):

So I found that if I change the media type before iTunes "processes" the file I'm able to set it as podcast. After it's already been processed I'm not able to do it. So I just deleted my file from iTunes, re-added it, and was able to edit the media type.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hidden tag, I ended up removing all tags using [TagStripper](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/tag-stripper/id432262744?mt=12) and then redoing them.